# Jquery find id beside href

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How can I make with jQuery something like this:

1) If I click to link, it fadeIn div element with same id just like href of clicked link.

My script is here

```
var search = $("#bottom").find("a"),
    hotels = $(".hotels").find("div").hide();

search.on("click", function (e) {
    $(this.hash).hotels("#hash").show();
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Whole snipet here http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MwNEgr

Comment: "*with same id*". **Not possible**. ID *must* be unique within the DOM.

Comment: same id *as the href* which is fine.

Answer (score 5):

Change your anchors as follows:

```
<a href="#flight">Flights</a>
<a href="#hotel">Hotels</a>
<a href="#cars">Cars</a>
```

Otherwise, the hash will include the URL.

You can then use this method, and note that you no longer need `preventDefault()`:

```
search.on('click', function () {
  hotels.hide();
  $(this.hash).fadeIn();
});
```

[**Updated CodePen**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bdXLyv)

Answer (score 0):

```
search.on("click", function (e) {
   var id = "#" + $(this).attr("href");
    $(id).show();
});
```

Or you can put "#" in href itself ("#hotels") and then it's

```
var id = $(this).attr("href");
```

Answer (score 0):

Here try this :

```
search.on("click", function (e) {
 e.preventDefault();
 $(".hotels").find("div").hide();
 var target = $(this).attr('href');
 $('#'+target).fadeIn();

});
```

**[DEMO](http://codepen.io/metallurgical/pen/eNqVao)**